# Notepad++ Unwanted syntax Highlighting for Markdown

Tags: notepad++, markdown, syntax-highlighting

Following the latest update for NPP on Windows 10, my markdown is now highlighted like in the image below (I know it's Python code, that's not the point).

I want completely plain code for Markdown - just white on black. However I can't find an option to set this in the setting menu as Markdown doesn't appear as a language.

Please help. This has seriously messed with my workflow.

[image]

Comment: *Following the latest update …* - did you mean version 7.7.1? Avoiding an update to 7.7.1 I tried to reproduce your problem with Notepad++ Version 7.7 - the problem did not appear!

Answer (score 16):

I have had identical issue and it turned out that I have installed user defined language that was not compatible with my current N++ style.

You can go to %APPDATA%\Notepad++\userDefineLangs and check whether you have some unwanted definitions there. You can also check it in Language menu - there is a big chance .md files opens with *User-defined* or some installed language.

Obviously, you can find and install user defined style that suits your N++ style and get something actually useful like I did (try https://github.com/Edditoria/markdown-plus-plus)

Comment: Removing the file at `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\userDefineLangs` worked for me. I suppose I could have also edited it to look nicer, but it wasn't worth the extra work for me.

Comment: I think removing the file at `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\userDefineLangs`  should be the accepted answer. For me the whole point of Markdown is to not have to think about formatting and styling etc. Please note my path was slightly different - I went to `%APPDATA%` and searched for `Notepad++`. I think in future the developers should make using plain styling for Markdown easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the menu Language > and choose "Markdown (preinstalled)"